# What happens when we assign zero to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

In the book [C How to Program, 8/e](https://deitel.com/c-how-to-program-8-e/) by Paul and Harvey Deitel it is written, under the section Initializing and Assigning Values to Pointers, that  "When 0 is assigned, it’s first converted to a pointer of the appropriate type. The value 0 is the only integer value that can be assigned directly to a pointer variable."   It is also written in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477247/20012207).

What do they mean by the it? What does it mean for zero to be converted to a pointer of the appropriate type? Can a value be type converted?

Comment: It means you can write `int *p = 0;` but not `int *p = 5;`

Comment: This Q/A explains the relation between an all-zero binary value and a null pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211439/is-memsetptr-0-sizeofptr-the-same-as-ptr-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean for zero to be converted to a pointer of the appropriate type?

An integer constant zero is treated specially; when it is converted to a pointer, the result is a null pointer. A null pointer is a special value designated to mean that the pointer does not point to any object or function.

> Can a value be type converted?

Conversions in C are type conversions. Generally, a conversion is a function or operation that takes a value in one type and produces the same value in another type, if possible. (If the value is not representable in the result type, the conversion should produce the closest representable value in some sense.)

For example, when the `int` value three is converted to `short`, the result is three. When it is converted to `float`, the result is three. When the `float` value 3.5 is converted to `int`, the result cannot be 3.5, since 3.5 is not representable in `int`. Instead, three is produced, which is the closest representable value in the direction toward zero.

When zero is converted to a pointer, its meaning of “nothing” is preserved, as the resulting pointer, a null pointer, points to “nothing.”

> “… The value 0 is the only integer value that can be assigned directly to a pointer variable.”

That is not well stated. Technically, it is not correct. The C standard’s rules for an assignment operator treat a constant integer value of zero as special and allow it to be assigned to a pointer without warning. This is to allow pointers to be set to a null pointer value with code like `p = 0;`.

The statement is not correct because it is only integer constants for which this is true. In `int x = 0; char *p = x;`, the `x` is not subject to this special treatment, as it is a variable, not a constant. The C standard’s rules require a C implementation to issue a diagnostic message for this.

Integers other than zero may be converted to a pointer type, by using a cast. The C standard does not fully define how these conversions operate. In particular, when a non-constant expression with value zero is converted to a pointer, the standard does not guarantee it produces a null pointer. It does in most C implementations, but this is not required by the C standard. Most C implementations define conversions between integers and pointers to operate in the normal way you would expect for the underlying hardware’s memory address scheme. In such implementations, you can convert an integer value that is a memory address to a pointer, and the result will be a pointer to that address. However, the rules for using such conversions are somewhat complicated when all of the C standard’s rules are considered.

Answer (score 4):

It simply means that a C compiler must treat the literal integer value `0` to indicate a NULL pointer.

i.e.

```
int * x = 0;
```

and

```
int * x = NULL;
```

... are guaranteed to be equivalent, even on [unusual hardware](https://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) where the address pointed to by a NULL pointer isn't actually address zero.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:

- Any pointer type to "something" can get its value turned into a *null pointer*, which is a pointer pointing at a well-defined nowhere.
- When a pointer is a null pointer, it has some sort of magic internal representation that we as programmers supposedly shouldn't worry our pretty heads about. *Very likely* all zeroes on most systems, but in theory it could be something else.
- In order to turn something into a null pointer, we need to initialize/assign a *null pointer constant* to our pointer variable. Valid null pointer constants in C are `0`, `(void*)0)` or some other compile-time expression resulting in a constant expression with the value zero (like `0L` or `0+0` etc).
- A null pointer shouldn't get de-referenced but it can be compared with other pointers or with a null pointer constant, in order to check if it is a null pointer or not.
- For convenience, the standard library header `stddef.h` provides a pre-made null pointer constant `NULL`, which is the preferred and self-documented way to turn something into a null pointer, or to use when checking if something is a null pointer.
- (The upcoming C23 adds a new keyword `nullptr` with basically the same meaning and function as `NULL`, although it is available without including any header.)

---

"Language-lawyering"/the dirty details:

Regarding conversions, what applies during initialization and/or assignment of variables are "the rules of simple assignment", found in the C standard at C17 6.5.16.1, where one such rule of valid assignment goes (emphasis mine):

> - **the left operand is an** atomic, qualified, or unqualified **pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant**

Since this is a valid form of assignment, the conversion rule that follows is:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment
> expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

The actual conversion is then described in C17 6.3.2.3:

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thank you very much.